# How to fail application on start up

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

I have a .net core application.  I need it to fail if it is not configured properly currently It continues running and I get I need it to shut down.

[image]

My configure services looks something like this.  There must be a way to get the application to stop when its incorrectly configured.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {

        if (Configuration["settings:connectionString"] == null) return;

   }
```

**Throwing Exception**

Does not stop the application all it does is leave this in my logs

> Application startup exception: System.ArgumentNullException: Value
>   cannot be null. Parameter name: settings:connectionString Not defined
>   correctly    at
>   Xena.IdentityServer.Startup.ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection
>   services) in
>   C:\Development\Xena\xena-identityserver\src\Xena.IdentityServer\Startup.cs:line
>   89
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.ConventionBasedStartup.ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection
>   services)    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost.EnsureApplicationServices()
>   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost.BuildApplication()
>   crit: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[6]
>         Application startup exception System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. Parameter name: settings:connectionString Not
>   defined correctly    at
>   Xena.IdentityServer.Startup.ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection
>   services) in
>   C:\Development\Xena\xena-identityserver\src\Xena.IdentityServer\Startup.cs:line
>   89
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.ConventionBasedStartup.ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection
>   services)    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost.EnsureApplicationServices()
>   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost.BuildApplication()

The site is still open and the same page above is visible.  I need the application to stop.

Comment: throw new Exception ?

Comment: Throwing an exception Does not stop the application it just leaves a message in my logs the application is still running.

Comment: Application.Exit();

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {

        if (Configuration["settings:connectionString"] == null)
        {
             // Log?
             System.Environment.Exit(160);
        }

   }
```

I've used `160` here since Microsoft conventions suggest this for 'bad arguments', I'm open to advice on that though.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/desktop/Debug/system-error-codes--0-499-

Comment: Nice one! Posted just 5 seconds before me:) Also, there is [FailFast()](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.environment.failfast?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Environment_FailFast_System_String_) method, that logs to system journal.

Answer (score 4):

Why can't you `throw` an exception like

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {

        if (Configuration["settings:connectionString"] == null) 
          throw new ArgumentNullException("settings:connectionString Not defined correctly");
   }
```

Comment: Throwing an exception does not stop the application its still running. I guess i should have mentioned that i had already tried that.

Comment: @DaImTo No it shouldn't unless it's handled somewhere in the caller ... I mean `try .. catch`

Comment: You may have missed the point.  I need this application to stop.   Throwing an exception does not stop the application its still running and serves the above error webpage.

Comment: @DaImTo so you need custom error page not stop app.

Comment: As an aside, you can see how the exceptions are handled here: https://github.com/aspnet/Hosting/blob/release/2.0/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting/WebHostBuilder.cs

Comment: @BWA no i need it to stop.  This is why i wrote that in the question.